# Data representation for multiple vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I have two items directory and movies. I need to represent a single directory with particular set of movies (only 4 per dir). Lets say we have 2 directories and 8 movies. 1 directory will contain 4 movies and another will contain 4. Programatically its like 0th directory contains: 0 to 3 movie ID's and 1st directory contains: 4 to 7 movie ID's. I've written the following code, but could not able to achieve what I need as shown in the expected output vs. original output with the help of vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int noofmovies = 4;

class Myclass{
private:
    int directory;
    vector<int> directories;
    vector<int> movies;
public:
    void read();
    void display() const;
};
void Myclass::read(){
    cout << "Enter number of directories: " << endl;
    cin >> directory;
    for(int i=0;i<directory;i++){
        directories.push_back(i);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<(directory*noofmovies);j++){
        movies.push_back(j);
    }
}
void Myclass::display() const{
    for(int i=0;i<directories.size();i++){
        cout << "directory[" << i << "]" << " contains " << endl;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<movies.size();j++){
        cout << "movies[" << j <<"]" <<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    Myclass my;
    my.read();
    my.display();
}
```

original output:

```
Enter number of directories:
2
directory[0] contains
directory[1] contains
movies[0]
movies[1]
movies[2]
movies[3]
movies[4]
movies[5]
movies[6]
movies[7]
```

expected output:

```
Enter number of directories:
2
directory[0] contains
movies[0]
movies[1]
movies[2]
movies[3]
directory[1] contains
movies[4]
movies[5]
movies[6]
movies[7]
```

Well I tried modifying the loops as below but the result is not what I wanted:

```
    void Myclass::read(){
    cout << "Enter number of directories: " << endl;
    cin >> directory;

    for(int i=0;i<directory;i++){
        directories.push_back(i);
        for(int j=0;j<noofmovies;j++){
            movies.push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
void Myclass::display() const{

    for(int i=0;i<directories.size();i++){
        cout << "directory[" << i << "]" << " contains " << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<movies.size();j++){
            cout << "movies[" << j <<"]" <<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `Myclass::display() const` member function. Both implementations of your other function are fine.

Your last attempt is the closest. Your only problem is the loop bounds of the nested `for` loop.

Currently you loop all `movies`, i.e.

```
for (int j=0 ; j < movies.size() ; j++)
```

This is incorrect, because it makes it look as if each directory owns *all* movies. However, directory `i` owns movies from `i*noofmovies`, inclusive, to `(i+1)*noofmovies`, exclusive. In other words, changing the inner loop to

```
for (int j=i*noofmovies ; j < (i+1)*noofmovies ; j++)
```

will fix your program.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the following code

```
void Myclass::display() const{
    int j = 0;    

    for(int i=0;i<movies.size();i++){
        if(i % noofmovies == 0){
            cout << "directory[" << j++ << "]" << " contains " << endl;
        }

        cout << "movies[" << i <<"]" <<endl;
    }
}
```

But you are not holding an actual link between directories and movies. In a real world scenario I think it would be better if Directory was a `class` that has a property `vector<int> movies`. And then you can iterate the `vector<Directory> directories` and for each `directory` to iterate its `movies`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion in the end. I will definitely build my program like you said : )

Comment: @highlander141 I believe that by using the answer of dasblinkenlight, although it requires minimal change in your code, you are sacrificing readability. By this I mean that it is not clear from a glance what is happening and why and for me this i very important.